# Выдача рандомных изображений по запросу VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

столкнулся с определенными проблемами…

У меня есть два (на самом деле их в районе 10-15) запроса (могу ошибаться в формулировке) на сервер в формате JSON
Пример: (второй запрос аналогичен, меняются только `id` и `album_id`)

```
{
"response": {
"count": 1995,
"items": [{
"id": 456240955,
"album_id": 238573272,
"owner_id": -133396686,
"user_id": 267622987,
"sizes": [...],
"text": "",
"date": 1479752858
}, {
"id": 456240956,
"album_id": 238573272,
"owner_id": -133396686,
"user_id": 267622987,
"sizes": [...],
"text": "",
"date": 1479752859
}]
}
}
```

Пример кода получения->отправки сообщений.

```
switch ($data->type) {
    case 'confirmation':
        echo $confirmation_token;
        break;

    case 'message_new':

switch ($user_msg) {
    case 'Скинь фото':
    case 'скинь фото':

    $m->msgSend("Держи фото", $user_id, $access_token);
        break;

    case "Скинь картинку":
    case "скинь картинку":

    $m->msgSend("Держи картинку.", $user_id, $access_token);
        break;
}
        echo('ok');
        break;
}
```

Суть проблемы/вопроса такова, как реализовать функцию при которой он будет записывать в отдельный документ (например: album_1.txt, album_2.txt) данные из JSON  (в формате photo-133396686_{`id`}) но будет брать `id` только из определенного альбома (без перемешивания).

То есть когда ему пишут "Скинь фото" он очищает файл, заносит туда все изображения из указанного альбома и отправляет в ответ случайное изображение из файла (например album_1.txt, а при отправке скинь картинку берет данные из album_2.txt).

Или как это можно упросить? Просто по факту выходит 10-15 файлов и пока сервер обработает всю информацию бегая с одного файла в другой, по времени будет ощутимо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отправки сообщения использовал

```
    case "":
    case "":

        $file = file_get_contents($config['album_8'], LOCK_EX);
        $photos_all = explode("\n", $file);

        $messages_send = array(

            'message' => "",
            'attachment' => $photos_all[mt_rand(0, count($photos_all) - 1)],
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'access_token' => $access_token,
            'v' => '5.50');

$get_params = http_build_query($messages_send);
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'.$get_params);
            break;
```

Для записи использовал

```
$config = [
'album_1' => 'albums/photos.txt',
];

            file_put_contents($config['album_1'], "", LOCK_EX);

            $album_json = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get?owner_id=-100129400&album_id={$album_id}&count=1000&access_token={$standalone_token}&v=5.92");
            $album_info = json_decode($album_json, true);

            foreach($album_info['response']['items'] as $value) {
                $result = 'photo'.$value['owner_id'].'_'.$value['id'];
                file_put_contents($config['album_1'], $result."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

---

Надеюсь кому-то пригодится